# core-js/babel-polyfill polyfilled functions appear as [native code]

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, babel-polyfill

Functions that were polyfilled with `core-js` (for example, `babel-polyfill`) appear as native.

`Promise.race.toString()` produces:

```
function race() {
    [native code]
}
```

So does `Object.values.toString()`.

While they are certainly not browser's native implementations. The example is [Babel REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/) page.

How can a developer programmatically check that a function is not native implementation but a polyfill that mimics native function (for instance, when it is known that a particular polyfill may cause problems in the application)?

Usually `native code` regexp helps, but it is certainly not the case.

How can source code be retrieved from such functions? I'm primarily interested in Node.js but cross-platform solution is welcome.

How exactly was this trick done? I cannot find nothing for `native code` search in `core-js` and `babel-polyfill` source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`core-js` attempts to make its polyfilled functionality appear as natively implemented by replacing `Function.prototype.toString` [here](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/16357e4fefa070573a342ef2a5692f30ba4320c6/modules/_redefine.js#L31) with a version that falls back on the default, but allows core-js to override the string value if it wants by setting a value at `fn[SRC]`.

You can see farther up in that file [here](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/16357e4fefa070573a342ef2a5692f30ba4320c6/modules/_redefine.js#L17) it assigns `fn[SRC]`, specifically

```
if(isFunction)has(val, SRC) || hide(val, SRC, O[key] ? '' + O[key] : TPL.join(String(key)));
```

If you inspect `TPL` in this case it is `["function ", "() { [native code] }"]`, so when called with `.join(String(key))` you end up with the

```
function race() { [native code] }
```

that you see in your output.

Comment: Great, this explains why `Promise.race.toString = Function.toString` had no effect when I've tried it.

Comment: Do you have ideas on another part of the question, how to test if a function was polyfilled? I guess you're one of the contributors, aren't you?

Comment: I think unfortunately that is a super hard thing to do. If you can get a reference to `Function.prototype.toString` from before `core-js` loaded, that would be easiest. Could you elaborate on what you're trying to detect it for? I have contributed a few things, but I'm mostly focused on Babel, so I'm not an expert either.

Comment: Just noticed 'SRC' properties all over polyfilled functions. It looks like there's no other way and this is what I was looking for. I had environment not very appropriate for debugging and and wasted some time investigating why Bluebird `Promise` is not there and why is there 'native' Promise (some dependency has loaded `babel-polyfill` on the quiet). I won't let this happen to me again. Thanks, `_redefine.js` was exactly the place I needed.

Comment: It seems the statement including TPL doesn't use the return value. So how does this work?

Answer (score 3):

Polyfilled `core-js` functions has [unique property which is defined by the library](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/v2.4.1/modules/_uid.js#L4) and stored internally, like `Symbol(src)_1.g50a4eqv8s8xgvi`. This allows the library to identify them and forge `toString()` results (as the other answer thoroughly explains).

It is possible to detect unique property and cheat `core-js` into revealing real function body:

```
function getPolyfillUid(fn) {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(fn).find(prop => /^Symbol\(.+\)_/.test(prop))
}

function toTrueString(fn) {
    const uid = getPolyfillUid(fn);
    let fnString;
    if (uid) {
        const uidDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(fn, uid);
        delete fn[uid];
        fnString = fn.toString();
        Object.defineProperty(fn, uid, uidDescriptor);
    } else {
        fnString = fn.toString();
    }

    return fnString;
}
```